# How to run IDE on local system and debug remotely

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ide, remote-debugging

I'm interested in programming a remote Linux system which is running in console mode.

I want to develop with an IDE locally and program, run and debug the system remotely.

Remote desktop won't work as it's running command line and I like IDEs/GUIs.

Both systems are running Ubuntu 22,

How would this normally be set up? I can SSH into the system but how do I set up an IDE running on my desktop to control the computer/debugger/terminal on the remote system?

Answer (score 2):

I only tried this with VS Code, in which case you just need to install the "Remote Developement" extension to connect to a remote host or a WSL.
So, if you're using VS Code,you can check out [the Visual Studio Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview) for further instructions on how to set up the remote connection.
I don't know which solutions there are for other IDEs, but I could imagine that there might exist similar extensions depending on which IDE you are using.